# needs to restart supervisor everytime

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-rest-framework

i am using postgres sql and here is my queryset

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
class QuizRankingPerDay(ListViewSetMixin):
queryset = User
serializer_class = LeaderBoardSerializer
pagination_class = CustomPagination

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    user_attempt_quiz_obj = UserAttemptQuiz.objects.filter(created_at__year=today.year,
                                                           created_at__month=today.month,
                                                           created_at__day=today.day)

    return user_attempt_quiz_obj.values('user').annotate(score=Sum("score_count")).order_by("-score")
```

queryset is working fine but its response doesn't change for each days untill i restart my server. i am using nginx server with supervisor

my time setting is below:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: Where and how do you run this code?

Comment: code is deployed on aws with nginx server
so i do sudo service supervisor restart

Comment: I don't really care about the machine it runs on. You have to tell us where the code is placed in your project and how it is execute (your stack as in stacktrace). The best would be if you create a minimal working example that demonstrated the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you instantiate today variable when your worker runs and it stays the same until you restart it. You need to show us the view or whatever is instantiating today.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is exactly what I described. Your today is instantiated once when you start your worker. You simply need to move today = date.today() inside get_queryset and you'll be fine.